# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '..\x08_epoch_model_state.pt'

Tags: python

when i run this `state = torch.load('..\10_epoch_model_state.pt', map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)`, i'm getting this error. how to fix it : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '..\x08_epoch_model_state.pt'

Answer (score 1):

`'\10'` is the character with ASCII code 10 in octal:

```
>>> '\10'
'\x08'
```

Use raw string literals:

```
>>> r'\10'
'\\10'
```